# Filling half a shape in figma

Tags: vector, shapes, figma

I am still pretty new to figma, so I am still learning. I have a shape (rectangle shape) that is all white. I am trying to "fill" half of the shape with a yellow color. Does anyone know how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Figma user, but the following method should work in all vector image editing software.

1. Create one rectangle with a white fill
2. Create a second rectangle on top, but half the size, and fill that with yellow.
3. If you also need an outline, copy and paste the white rectangle on top, and apply a stroke and no fill.
4. You can then select all the objects and group them.

[image]